# Node.js and Apache: connection issues

Tags: node.js, centos, socket.io

I have installed Node.js with Socket.io on a CentOS server which is running Apache on port 80.
I created a socket test, which justs listens on port 8080.

If I curl the address localhost:8080 from within the server's shell, I get the Socket.io-welcome message. If I have a line like this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Then the browser cannot find the file.

A "solution" was to proxy requests to `/nodejs/` to `http://localhost:8080/`, but this solution did not work for very long.

Is it possible to run the Node.js server when we have Apache installed? Which settings must be changed in order for us to access the url: `http://server.com:8080` ? It seems the Node.js only accepts connections from localhost.

Comment: Apache might not be out-of-box comaptible with WebSockets

Comment: maybe port 8080 is blocked by you firewall?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is most probably in your node.js program. 
It should listen on `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1` which is local only.

So where you've got something like:

```
.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1'); // '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost'
```

You should change it to:

```
.listen(8080); // or 0.0.0.0
```

Apache will only interfere if it also uses port 8080 but you should get an error when starting your node app if this is the case.

Also, if you connect to `http://localhost` in your browser, it will only work if the server is on the same local machine as the browser. Fine for testing I guess.

You'll have to connect to a domain or ip address if you have a hosted server else no browser will find it.

Update:
Your socket.io code also needs to connect correctly:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://correct.server.com:8080'); // not localhost
```

and your browser needs to load the javascript file from the correct place:

```
<script src="http://correct.server.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> // not localhost
```

This might help with firewall / load balancer issues:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, it did not seem to do the trick. Our server is behind a load balancer; will this interfere? If I go through Apache (proxy), this will output in Firebug (before falling back to xhr polling): 
`"NetworkError: 502 Bad Gateway - http://server.com/nodejs/socket.io/1/websocket/Zp2XXL10rKJALNuKmw6t"

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://server/nodejs/socket.io/1/websocket/Zp2XXL10rKJALNuKmw6t`

Comment: I'm not sure about the load balancer. You need to make sure that port 8080 will reach your server form anywhere. If you've got your node server running on `0.0.0.0` anything able to reach it will be able to connect to it. After this make sure you load your .js file from the appropriate url (not localhost) and make sure that the socket.io code connects correctly. I'll update my answer above to demonstrate. If that's all in place and its still not working I'm stumped for now :)

Comment: OK here's what I did: 
Created a HTTP sub domain, and proxied requests with HAproxy. Did not work 100 %, as we are connecting from an HTT`S` sub domain. For some reason, HAproxy did not send the socket-data back to the client from the socket, resulting in timeout. The socket was logging that is was sending data the whole time. Proxying with Apache did not work. Creating a sub-sub-domain on the `HTTPS` sub domain resulted in certificate warnings. The only solution that proved OK, was to open the port in the load balancer, and connect: `https://sub.server.com:8080`. Thank you for your input!